# SignalR Self Host Connection Reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR hosted in IIS and I have set it up following [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) tutorial from Microsoft. When I go to connect to the hub, I get a console error which is

```
GET https://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Has anyone else come accross this error setting up SignalR or anything in IIS and have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? see http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms for iis7 or iis7.5 you need to install http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Comment: I get the same failure using IIS 8 express so I don't think it is the hotfix that is needed. SignalR seems really cool, I just can't seem to deploy it to a real IIS server...  Can anyone help Frank and I?

Comment: The key thing here is the HTTPS because you need to create a self-signed certificate in your local machine to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is the HTTPS because you need to create a self-signed certificate in your local machine to make it work.

See this link: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/sep/23/hosting-signalr-under-sslhttps#UsingIIStocreateaself-signedCertificate